# SQL max function with another condition not working

Tags: sql, max

This works perfectly until an order comes in where the stationID is not =2. My logic would be that sql searches where both conditions meet and display those results and not look where timeplaced is max then if stationid does not =2 display nothing which is what its doing.

```
SELECT OrderNo 
FROM   Orders 
WHERE  TimePlaced = (SELECT max(TimePlaced) FROM Orders) 
       AND StationID=2
```

Comment: Can multiple orders with same `StationID` have same `TimePlaced`?

Comment: Also, what SQL product are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Add your condition into the inner select too

```
SELECT OrderNo 
FROM   Orders 
WHERE  TimePlaced = 
       (
           SELECT max(TimePlaced) 
           FROM   Orders 
           WHERE  StationID=2
       ) 
       AND StationID=2
```

But if you do not want to add the condition twice, then just "link" the inner select with the outer:

```
SELECT OrderNo 
FROM   Orders O
WHERE  TimePlaced = 
       (
           SELECT max(TimePlaced) 
           FROM   Orders 
           WHERE  StationID=O.StationID
       ) 
       AND StationID=2
```

Another way you could try would be with using a `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH OrdersCTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StationID ORDER BY TimePlaced Desc) AS rn
    FROM   Orders
)
SELECT * 
FROM   OrdersCTE 
WHERE  rn = 1
       AND StationID = 2
```

Comment: Wow that was quick thank you so much. Could you also help me out with something else. Im trying to get the rows to format a special way. I have a pos system and I developed an application displaying the orders for the drivethru. I got the items and prices displaying correctly which was pretty simple but i cannot figure out how to display modifications to each item if one exists. For example display all items from some orderno... then for item1 row right under display sideitem text where detailid(which links to item) = item1 if one exists else go on to item 2.

Comment: I think the best way for you do get proper results would be 1. Update your question, 2. Give details of your related tables schemas 3. Give a sample of data in those tables 4. Give an example of expected results. Optionally you may flavor your question with images etc. You could also help whoever provides answers with having your sample data in `SQLFiddle`.

Comment: I apologize if links are not allowed but i couldnt upload any images since im new. I think that image is pretty detailed if you could take a look at it. I really appreciate it.

Comment: table name for the first table is dbo.Orders. second table is dbo.OrderDetail. Third Table is dbo.orderdetailincludes. And last table is dbo.orderdetailoptions

Comment: Sorry im not exactly understanding what im supposed to do on sqlfiddle.